# won't display CSS Background-Image

Tags: html, css

as i write where the image is located at it won't find it in the directory. No matter what i do i tried quotations, no-quotations,switching the directory, still no help only when i put my image outside of a folder, is when i am able to see the image. Here is my example of my code:

```
#Story {
background-image: url('Images/Story.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:45px;
width:75px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ededed;
float:left;
padding:13px;
font-family:"Helvetica";
font-size:18px;
```

}

Comment: how does your directory look? where is your css? is it externally?

Answer (score 2):

The path is relative to the css file .. this might be your issue ..

Comment: Thank You i found the issue and it was exactly that